# Get result into the caller from a function returning std::optional of std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional

I am trying to manipulate the `std::optional` using container like `std::vector`.

I started by doing the code below :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

using namespace std;

using optional_vecs = std::optional<std::vector<std::string>>;

optional_vecs returnStrings()
{
    optional_vecs myVect(std::in_place); 
    myVect->emplace_back("Name");
    return myVect;
}

int main()
{
    for (auto e : returnStrings().value())
        std::cout << e << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that I get nothing in the output: I guess that because `std::optional::value` return a reference as in my case it is a reference to a temporary.

So to resolve that I tried to use `std::reference_wrapper` as below :

```
using optional_vecs = std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<std::string>>>;

optional_vecs returnStrings()
{
    optional_vecs myVect; 
    myVect->get().emplace_back("Name");
    return myVect;
}
```

Now I got a crash and an error :

- the crash happens when trying to add the string "name".
- the error is when I try to use the `for-range` loop saying `the range for loop requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found.`

The code below works but I don't like to declare a variable and then calli the Value():

```
int main()
{
    auto result = returnStrings();
    for (auto e : result.value())
        std::cout << e << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

So how could I return an std::optional holding a `std::vector` in the way `functionName().Value()`.

Comment: What's the point of optional vector? Why not simply return an empty vector? Well, if empty vector means something other than no vector... but it is still rather pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue here in the first two cases is that since `returnStrings()` returns a temporary, the for loop will not extend its life unless you actually capture what it returns.  Capturing `result.value()` doesn't do you any good since it will not extend the lifetime of `returnStrings()`.

> So how could I return an std::optional holding a std::vector in the way `functionName().Value()`.

You have to capture the return of `functionName()`.  You can do what you did, or in C++20 you can use the new *init-statement* version of ranged for which was built for cases like this and would look like

```
for (auto&& opt_vec =  returnStrings(); auto e : opt_vec.value())
    std::cout << e << " ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you have to use the latter construct.

The `optional` object is responsible for owning the `vector`. C++ won't recursively extend lifetimes to the object owning a referenced object, so if that owning object is destroyed (which it will be, because it's temporary), the referenced object will also be destroyed.

One thing I will point out though: at least as far as GCC is concerned, [this is valid code](https://godbolt.org/z/qRZxmC):

```
int main()
{
    for (auto ret = returnStrings(); auto e : ret.value())
        std::cout << e << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Changing to `optional<reference_wrapper<vector>>` also doesn't work because the original `returnStrings` function is returning an rvalue, meaning if it weren't for copy elision, that original object would be move-assigned and then destructed as well.

So if it's vitally important that the function return an `optional<vector>`, your for-loop will need to have something that properly initializes the optional object itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with `std::optional` wrapper as you work with it's template underlying type. In your case, it's `std::string`, that should work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

using namespace std;

using optional_vecs = std::optional<std::vector<std::string>>;

optional_vecs returnStrings()
{
    std::vector<std::string> myVect{};
    myVect.emplace_back("Name");
    return std::optional{ myVect };
}

int main()
{
    auto stringsOpt = returnStrings();

    if (stringsOpt) {
        for (auto& e : *stringsOpt)
            std::cout << e << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code actually works on GCC.

P.S. : it's surprisingly, but your source code doesn't compile on MSVC.